# deletes from many-to-many are not syncronized to the db

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, many-to-many

I have a many to many relation between entities "Car" and "Pakete" and I try to remove the links between them by removing from both ends:

```
public Pakete removeAllLinksFromPacket(int packetId) {
    Pakete p = em.find(Pakete.class, packetId);
    if ( null != p ) {
        for(Car c : p.getCars() )  {
            c.getPakets().remove(p);
            // em.merge(c);
        }
        p.getCars().clear();
        // em.merge(p);
        // em.flush();
    }
    return p;
}
```

When I execute the above code, the links are removed within the persistence context of the current session, however the changes are not syncronized to the db. If I then stop and restart the session, the links show up again :-(. The commented out em.merge() and em.flush()es were just a desperate attempt.

The server is a glassfish 3.1.2

The entities look as follows:

```
@Table(name="cars")
public class Car implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private CarPK id;

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Pakete
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
    name="cars_pakete"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="uid", referencedColumnName="uid"),
        @JoinColumn(name="car_name", referencedColumnName="name"),  
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="paket_id")
        }
    )
    private Set<Pakete> paketes;
        public Car() {
        }

    public CarPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(CarPK id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

        // ... other members getter/setter removed
}
```

and

```
@Table(name="pakete")
public class Pakete implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    // ... some member variables removed

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Car
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="paketes")
    private Set<Car> cars;

    public Pakete() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Car> getCars() {
        return this.cars;
    }

    public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    // ... some getter/setter removed
}
```

There is an existing DB and I generated the above entities with eclipse jpa tools.

What am I missing. I can of cause, as a work around, execute a native query on the join table. But I have not given up the hope that somebody can explain me what is going on here.

Thanks in advance.

I changed the code into:

```
public Pakete removeAllLinksFromPacket(int packetId) {
    Pakete p = em.find(Pakete.class, packetId);
    if ( null != p ) {
        List<Car> lc = new ArrayList<Car>();
        lc.addAll(p.getCars());
        if ( lc.isEmpty() )
            throw new NullPointerException("no links");             
        for(Car c : lc ) {
            if ( !c.getPaketes().contains(p) )
                throw new NullPointerException("no packet");
            c.getPaketes().remove(p);

            if ( !p.getCars().contains(c) )
                throw new NullPointerException("no car");
            p.getCars().remove(c);
        }
    } else
        throw new NullPointerException("No packet found");

    return p;
}
```

and added some assert-like exceptions just to make sure. It didn't give any clues.

In one use-case, the function itself is called by another function that first removes all links and then adds new links. It looks like this:

```
@Override
public void mapCarsToPacket(int packetId,
    List<String> carNames) {
    // 1. remove all existing links
    Pakete p = eao.removeAllLinksFromPacket(packetId);

    // 2. add the new links
    for (String cn : carNames ) {
        List<Car> cars = eao.getCarsWithName(cn);
        for(Car c : cars ) {
            p.getCars().add(c);
            c.getPaketes().add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

So this function runs within a transaction and when I execute it, the old packets are still not removed from the db **but the new links are inserted**. The database then contains the new and the old list. When the lists overlapp, e.g. new list contains a car that is already linked, I get a DBException because of a unique-constrain violation.

But, if the packet itself is removed like this:

```
public void deletePacketAndAllItsLinks(int id) {
    Pakete p = removeAllLinksFromPacket(id);
    if ( null != p ) {
        em.remove(p);
    }
}
```

oh wonder, the packet and all its links in the join-table are deleted.

Stunned...

For the time being: **I give up!** This is realy awful, but it works:

```
public Pakete removeAllLinksFromPacket(int packetId) {
    em.flush();
    em.clear();
    em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM cars_pakete WHERE paket_id=?").setParameter(1, packetId).executeUpdate();
    Pakete p = em.find(Pakete.class, packetId);
    if ( null != p ) {
        List<Car> lc = new ArrayList<Car>();
        lc.addAll(p.getCars());
        for(Car c : lc ) {
            c.getPaketes().remove(p);               
            p.getCars().remove(c);
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

I'm keeping the persistence context in sync myself. This is sure not the spirit of JPA and I realy hate it. However, I can proceed with my project. Thanks to anybody who tried to help. Any future sugestions which lead to a JPA conform solution are gratefuly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you make your changes in an active transaction, and that you commit the transaction.  Also make sure the collection was not empty to begin with.

Try enabling logging on finest, and include the log.

Comment: It is running within a container managed transaction and there is no log because the entities are **not** syncronized. No error, no exception, no nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the same problem.

I have nearly the same situation, I have two join columns in the many to many relationship, but only one is set by the JPA container. The other one is filled with a null value (but only when deleting -> leads to nothing deleted on the database because the query with a null value in the where clause does not match any row). Inserting works fine without any issues...

Maybe you can log the statements to you DBMS and confirm that?